# Unable to find version " " of package " "

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, nuget, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to deploy my website from github to Azure but there are some errors showing up every time I try to do it, this is part of the log from Azure:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment with MSBuild.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.1.0.0.
Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.1.0.0.
Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.1.0.0.
WARNING: Unable to find version '1.0.0' of package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions'.
  D:\home\.nuget: Package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.1.0.0' is not found on source 'D:\home\.nuget'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Could not find file 'D:\home\.nuget\microsoft.extensions.caching.abstractions\1.0.0\microsoft.extensions.caching.abstractions.1.0.0.nupkg'.
```

It does that for a lot of `Nuget` packages that I have, maybe all of them.

Then after the Warning messages, this other message is showed:

```
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\src\LIGMarine\project.json...
Restoring packages for tool 'BundlerMinifier.Core' in D:\home\site\repository\src\LIGMarine\project.json...
Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools' in D:\home\site\repository\src\LIGMarine\project.json...
Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools' in D:\home\site\repository\src\LIGMarine\project.json...
Committing restore...
Writing lock file to disk. Path: D:\home\site\repository\src\LIGMarine\project.lock.json
D:\home\site\repository\src\LIGMarine\LIGMarine.xproj
Restore completed in 5151ms.
```

And then comes the error messages:

```
Errors in packages.config projects
    Unable to find version '1.0.0' of package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions'.
      D:\home\.nuget: Package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.1.0.0' is not found on source 'D:\home\.nuget'.
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Could not find file 'D:\home\.nuget\microsoft.extensions.caching.abstractions\1.0.0\microsoft.extensions.caching.abstractions.1.0.0.nupkg'.

Feeds used:
    D:\home\.nuget
      D:\home\.nuget: Package 'System.Interactive.Async.3.0.0' is not found on source 'D:\home\.nuget'.
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Could not find file 'D:\home\.nuget\system.interactive.async\3.0.0\system.interactive.async.3.0.0.nupkg'
```

This is a resume of the Azure log, I have read about this errors and I have created a Nuget.Config file as I show in the picture, this file is inside the `Solution Items` folder[image]

This is the code that I have inside the `Nuget.Config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources />
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

According to this messages, the Nuget packages cannot be found...

```
Feeds used:
    D:\home\.nuget
      D:\home\.nuget: Package 'System.Interactive.Async.3.0.0' is not found on source 'D:\home\.nuget'.
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Could not find file 'D:\home\.nuget\system.interactive.async\3.0.0\system.interactive.async.3.0.0.nupkg'
```

Maybe it's not looking for the packages the way it should, I'm not sure what means this path: `'D:\home\.nuget\'`

What should I do?

**EDIT**
These are the packages that are not being found, I don't think these are private packages that cannot be found within https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
System.Interactive.Async
System.Linq
System.Linq.Expressions
System.Linq.Queryable
System.Globalization
System.Reflection
System.ObjectModel
System.Resources.ResourceManager
System.Reflection.Extensions
System.Runtime
System.Runtime.Extensions
System.Runtime.InteropServices
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions


System.Threading.Tasks
System.Threading.Tasks.4.0.11
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.1.0.0
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
Microsoft.Extensions.Options
Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives
Remotion.Linq
Newtonsoft.Json
System.Collections
System.Collections.Immutable
System.Diagnostics.Debug
System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource
System.Collections.Concurrent
System.ComponentModel
System.Threading
```

.

Comment: Have you tried to disable local nuget cache (-nocache)? And also setting -verbosity=detailed might help diagnose the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new website in Azure and now it works, it seems that the previous website was deploying a previous application from Github and there were some conflicts, everything works fine now